# How to implement multiple column headers on ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, columnheader

Like on the pic, there is second column header and two subheaders under it ?

[image]

Comment: Is that even possible in the list view control? Looks like you have a custom control there.

Comment: @David, is there any chance to implement it as custom control in c# ?

Comment: Steven do you have existing code that you are working with..it would help to see that I would like to make sure you are getting the proper solution, based on the Picture thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complete example look at this link this should give you a full working example of what you can do
[Add ListView Column and Insert Listview Items](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/AddListViewcolumnandinsertListViewrows.htm)

try something like this

The order in which you add values to the array dictates the column they appear under so think of your sub item headings as [0],[1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/AddListViewcolumnandinsertListViewrows.htm) etc.

Here's a code sample:

//In this example an array of three items is added to a three column listview
string[] saLvwItem = new string[2];

```
foreach (string wholeitem in listofitems)
{
     saLvwItem[0] = "Status Message";
     saLvwItem[1] = wholeitem;
     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(saLvwItem);

     lvwMyListView.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

To add SubItems you could also do something like this

```
lvwMyListView.Items[0].SubItems.Add("John Smith");
```

Comment: That's just a standard 3 column list view. Question appears to differ.

Comment: David I will alter my answer to show the 2 sub headers.. I didn't see that at first. good catch