# Column headers spanning more than one column in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

My required functionality concerns multiple columns grouped under a single header cell in Winforms vb.net/C# .Net 4.7.

Each column is still separate, it's just the label that changes.

```
|        header           |
---------------------------
|        |        |       |
|        |        |       |
|        |        |       |
```

Appreciating this isn't a built in feature, (nor probably recommended). I've had a few ideas.

1. Place a rectangle graphic on the "fused" headers
2. Target the required column headers and render their separators transparent, then play about with the alignment of one header in order to make it seem like its columns are grouped.

This question seems to have been covered a lot for the `DataGridView` component, [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44622c0-74e1-463b-97b9-27b87513747e/windows-forms-data-controls-and-databinding-faq?forum=winformsdatacontrols#faq6). The opted solution involves handling the `DataGridView.Painting` and `DataGridView.CellPainting` events. Both of which are not available for the `ListView`.

I was wondering whether anyone had any ideas for reproducing this solution for the `ListView`?

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080614/how-to-implement-multiple-column-headers-on-listview), although accepted, does not provide a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement multiple column headers on ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080614/how-to-implement-multiple-column-headers-on-listview)

Comment: While accepted I don't think the link actually has a solution.. LV __does__ have a DrawHeader event, though!

Comment: The accepted solution does indeed not correctly relate to that particular question.

Comment: Using the `DrawColumnHeader` event, as TaW suggested, allows you to have a single Column but each column will remain sizable, i.e, the column handle on the header will still be usable.

Comment: In case you don't need to resize the Columns, you could set the LV `HeaderStyle` to `none` and paint a *fake* one using default system colors.

Comment: I've made some progress using the DrawHeader event, for example:

            `Dim region = New Region(New Rectangle(New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.width * 2, e.Bounds.Height)`

            `e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.Red, region)`


However, I'm unable to leave the bounds set by the header rectangle so can only fill that header. Any idea how I can go beyond the bounds of the particular header captured by the event?

Comment: You could draw the first Column only, extending it to the overall width of the Columns. Something like: `if (e.ColumnIndex != 0) return; int allWidth = e.Header.ListView.Columns.OfType<ColumnHeader>().Sum(h => h.Width);`. Then create a rectangle using the `e.Bounds` value where the Location is the same and the new Size is `Size(allWidth, e.Bounds.Height - 2)`. Then fill the rectangle/region and draw the contour on these new bounds.